# Can we use "workaround to this" instead of "solution to this"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

While searching for the meaning I got this:

> **Workaround** - a method for overcoming a problem or limitation in a program or system.

Which means almost the same as "**solution**".
So, can we use "*workaround to this*" instead of "*solution to this*" in a sentence?

For example,

- This issue is getting more complicated. I want a **workaround to this**.
- Math is not real fun unless you have the **workaround to these equations**.

Is it okay to use this combination in a sentence? Does it hold a different meaning?

And what are the other precautions?

Comment: In my world (software support), "workaround" is usually not a good thing since it implies that there's something wrong with the product or process and an alternate way to solve the problem is employed.  It is a solution, just not one I'd like the end-users to employ - except in the case of an emergency and then just until a permanent solution can be developed, fixed or deployed.

Comment: When you use a workaround, the problem still exists, you've just found a way to live with it. A solution to a problem is expected to fix it.

Comment: 'Workaround' is a modern compound. Prepositions (other than in their central spatial & temporal usages) tend to collocate with nouns on a (now) apparently rather arbitrary basis. We use answer / solution _to_ (a question / problem), where _for_ might be more logically expected. 'Workaround' has probably not been around long enough to collocate with a preposition other than the logical 'for'.

Comment: People have said to me 'We do not have a solution, but there is a quickfix you can do'. Workaround = quickfix?

Comment: @WS2 no a quick fix could be a permanent solution and fix implies it is a correct solution not a workaround

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Workaround
>   A method for overcoming a problem or limitation in a program or system.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20workaround)
>
> Solution
>   A means of solving a problem or dealing with a difficult situation.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20solution)

A workaround is a way of avoiding the problem.

A solution fixes the problem.

They do both have the same outcome, but a workaround is like covering up a patch of damp with wall paper, rather than getting it waterproofed.

Comment: I have searched on various sites for the answer and I think this explains better than any other.

Comment: So can we say 'workaround' as 'temporary solution'?