# Use of "workarounds"

Tags: word-usage

Let's say there is problem X, and I have in mind some methods, each is a workaround for X.

For a single workaround, it seems fine to say: "I am suggesting a workaround X", but I feel the following do not sound right, or at least there are better ways to phrase them:

- I am suggesting workarounds for X
- I am suggestions workarounds, each of them address X

What's the best way to connect "workarounds" and "X" ?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193963/can-we-use-workaround-to-this-instead-of-solution-to-this

Comment: 'I am suggesting workarounds for X'  seems to be perfectly adequate. What problem do you think there might be with that?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK To me it sounds a bit weird because in the singular form there is no need to use "for", you just say: "a workaround this problem".

Comment: @MohamedKhamis No, you do not. _For_ must be there in the singular as well. “I suggested a workaround this problem” is completely ungrammatical. You can say “I suggested that we work around this problem”, but that’s not the noun _workaround_. A workaround is always _for_ something (or _to_ something, _against_ something, or _in relation to_ something, etc.). This is exactly parallel to similar words like _solution_: “This is not a good solution our problem” is not grammatical, either—it must be “This is not a good solution _to_ our problem”.

Comment: @MohamedKhamis - That is where you are wrong. In fact I edited your question to correct that. Can you provide an example from somewhere  that leaves out the 'for'?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see.. so my doubts about the incorrectness of the plural form were based on an incorrect singular form :D could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I don't have an example but it just sounded strange, perhaps it felt like two consecutive propositions! but I guess the "around" in workaround is not.. and I should treat "workaround" as a noun like you said.

Comment: If you want it to be a verb then you can't say ' each is a workaround' You cannot use an indefinite article with a verb.

Comment: If you ever want to use the plural, *workarounds*, it will sound better to your ear (and mine!) if you put something in front of it, such as *some*, *several*, *any*, or a number, e.g. *"Tom told me you found some workarounds for Problem X";  "Yes, I believe I have found three reasonable workarounds, and I'd like to get your opinion."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the comments, you have confused 'to work around X' with 'a workaround for X'.

**Examples**

X is a big problem. I need to find a workaround to fix it. (noun)

X is a big problem. I need to find a workaround for it.  (noun)

X is a big problem. I need to work around it somehow. (verb)